# Postgresql index for this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

Is there any index that helps with this kind of query?

```
select p.name 
from person p 
where 'abjohncde' like '%'||p.name||'%'
```

An index using gin with gin_trgm_ops can be used for this query:

```
select p.name from person p where p.name like '%john%'
```

but gin doesn't work for the first query.

Comment: You need  a trigram index http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/

Answer (score 0):

`pg_trgm` works fine for cases like `select * from table where field like '%pattern%'` but unfortunatelly it does not helps in cases like `select * from table where 'abcde' like '%'||field||'%'` or `select * from table where 'abcde' ~ field` (which is semantically same but the first one much faster)

Instead, You can try to make something like trigram indexes manually:

```
create or replace function my_trgm(x text)
    returns text[]
    language sql
    immutable strict
as $$
    select
        case when length(x) > 3 then
            (select array_agg(distinct lower(substr(x, i, 3))) from generate_series(1, length(x)-2) as i)
            else array[x]
        end
$$;

create or replace function public.my_trgm_1(x text)
    returns text[]
    language sql
    immutable strict
as $$
    select
        (select array_agg(distinct lower(substr(x, i, 3))) from generate_series(1, length(x)-2) as i) ||
        (select array_agg(distinct lower(substr(x, i, 2))) from generate_series(1, length(x)-1) as i) ||
        (select array_agg(distinct lower(substr(x, i, 1))) from generate_series(1, length(x)) as i)
$$;
```

And test:

```
postgres=# create table t as select ((random()*1000)::int)::text as x from generate_series(1, 1000000);
SELECT 1000000
postgres=# create index idx_t_x on t using gin (my_trgm(x));
CREATE INDEX

postgres=# explain (analyze, verbose) select * from t where '16662' like '%'||x||'%';
                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..13216.67 rows=5000 width=3) (actual time=0.338..65.335 rows=8971 loops=1)
   Output: x
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public.t  (cost=0.00..11716.67 rows=2083 width=3) (actual time=0.106..59.276 rows=2990 loops=3)
         Output: x
         Filter: ('16662'::text ~~ (('%'::text || t.x) || '%'::text))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 330343
         Worker 0: actual time=0.089..57.952 rows=3126 loops=1
         Worker 1: actual time=0.124..58.830 rows=3308 loops=1
 Planning Time: 0.061 ms
 Execution Time: 65.803 ms

postgres=# explain (analyze, verbose) select * from t where my_trgm(x) <@ my_trgm_1('16662') and '16662' ~ x;
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on public.t  (cost=184.40..6916.58 rows=43 width=3) (actual time=4.655..70.851 rows=8971 loops=1)
   Output: x
   Recheck Cond: (my_trgm(t.x) <@ '{166,666,662,16,66,62,1,6,2}'::text[])
   Filter: ('16662'::text ~ t.x)
   Heap Blocks: exact=3876
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_t_x  (cost=0.00..184.39 rows=8586 width=0) (actual time=3.534..3.534 rows=8971 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (my_trgm(t.x) <@ '{166,666,662,16,66,62,1,6,2}'::text[])
 Planning Time: 0.578 ms
 Execution Time: 71.228 ms
```

Note that it performed on one-column table so scanning the whole table could be more efficient then scanning GIN index in this particular test case.

PS: Using some PL language like `plpythonu` or `plperl` could be more efficient for inserting/updating data.

Comment: There is a solution out-of-the box: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html and http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I understand it is solution for `field ~~ '%<pattern>%'` but not for `'<constant>' ~~ '%'||<field>||'%'`

Comment: that is brilliant, but somehow your solution takes longer as shown in your example as well as my actual use case. I will play with it a little more, tweak some and see.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @user3281157 If you using my solution as is... Do not use `~` operator - it is much costly then `~~` (synonym of `like` and `~~*` is synonym of `ilike`; I used `~` just because it is shorter :)